# How to SELECT a column based on a condition on the column's name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following table named MyTable:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| Code | U_Col1 | U_Col2 | U_Col3 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
|  123 |      1 |      2 |      3 |
|  456 |      4 |      5 |      6 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to write a query to give me the output based on the condition on the column's name. The names of the column are not fixed. They can be anything and come from another table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Value] (@Code VARCHAR(3), @Name VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN (

    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable T0
    WHERE T0.Code = @Code AND <columnname> = CONCAT('U_',@Name)
)
```

The expected output of

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_Value]('123','Col3')
```

is 3.

How do I get this kind of a `WHERE` condition to work? I realize I would normally do it with dynamic SQL, but I want to do this in an inline table-valued function, which won't allow me doing it dynamically.

I tried an UNPIVOT:

```
SELECT X.Value
FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Code = @Code) T
UNPIVOT (
Value FOR Name IN (@Name)
) AS X
```

But there is something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: You need to build your query string dynamically and [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it. Search this site for "dynamic SQL" for examples.

Comment: I can do it dynamically, I understand. The problem is I want to do it in an inline TVF and that won't allow me doing it dynamically.

Comment: You should put all relevant information into your question, instead of having people guess what you mean.

Comment: @mustaccio I apologize for my mistake.

Comment: If you're using this approach to improve development efficiency (by way of code optimization) this will very likely come at a cost of performance within the database as it's just not going to be efficient on any level.  [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) were made exactly for this reason and I suggest you look at one of the [existing platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) first before rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without dynamic SQL with some XML trickery.

Create XML of all values for each row and and use `local-name()` function to extract the value of the column you want.

Here is an example where you perhaps need to change the data types. I assumed integers.

```
create table dbo.T(Code int, U_Col1 int, U_Col2 int, U_Col3 int)

go

create function dbo.GetT
(
  @Name nvarchar(128),
  @Code int
)
returns table
as
return (
       select T.Code,
              C.X.value('(*[local-name() = sql:variable("@Name")]/text())[1]', 'int') as U_Col
       from dbo.T
         cross apply(select T.* for xml path(''), type) as C(X)
       where T.Code = @Code
       );
go

insert into dbo.T (Code, U_Col1, U_Col2, U_Col3) values
(123, 1, 2, 3),
(456, 4, 5, 6)

go

select * from dbo.GetT('U_Col1', 123);
select * from dbo.GetT('U_Col2', 456);
```

Note that the names of all columns in the table must be valid as element names in XML.

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=366d30a23dcf4da5e960579b0d62e0fa)

Comment: This approach worked. I was able to get the desired results without sacrificing too much on performance. But I am not well-versed with the XML functioning and not confident about the specific cases where this approach could fail. Would it be possible for you to share a good and easy-to-understand knowledge base/reference for understanding the used functions?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.t
WHERE 1 = 2
   OR (@name = 'Col1' AND t.U_col1 = @Code)   
   OR (@name = 'Col2' AND t.U_col2 = @Code)   
   OR (@name = 'Col3' AND t.U_col3 = @Code)
```

In this case you should call the external query (which is using the TVD) whith `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`

Answer (score -1):

Well you **could** use something like this (I used sys.tables as example table), but this would break every index usage (except you add some more filters) and could result in a very bad performance on big and broad tables:

```
SELECT sub.*
  FROM sys.tables AS t
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('name',                            CAST(t.name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('object_id',                       CAST(t.object_id                      AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('principal_id',                    CAST(t.principal_id                   AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('schema_id',                       CAST(t.schema_id                      AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('parent_object_id',                CAST(t.parent_object_id               AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('type',                            CAST(t.type                           AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('type_desc',                       CAST(t.type_desc COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS                      AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('create_date',                     CAST(t.create_date                    AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('modify_date',                     CAST(t.modify_date                    AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_ms_shipped',                   CAST(t.is_ms_shipped                  AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_published',                    CAST(t.is_published                   AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_schema_published',             CAST(t.is_schema_published            AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('lob_data_space_id',               CAST(t.lob_data_space_id              AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('filestream_data_space_id',        CAST(t.filestream_data_space_id       AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('max_column_id_used',              CAST(t.max_column_id_used             AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('lock_on_bulk_load',               CAST(t.lock_on_bulk_load              AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('uses_ansi_nulls',                 CAST(t.uses_ansi_nulls                AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_replicated',                   CAST(t.is_replicated                  AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('has_replication_filter',          CAST(t.has_replication_filter         AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_merge_published',              CAST(t.is_merge_published             AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_sync_tran_subscribed',         CAST(t.is_sync_tran_subscribed        AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('has_unchecked_assembly_data',     CAST(t.has_unchecked_assembly_data    AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('text_in_row_limit',               CAST(t.text_in_row_limit              AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('large_value_types_out_of_row',    CAST(t.large_value_types_out_of_row   AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_tracked_by_cdc',               CAST(t.is_tracked_by_cdc              AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('lock_escalation',                 CAST(t.lock_escalation                AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('lock_escalation_desc',            CAST(t.lock_escalation_desc           AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_filetable',                    CAST(t.is_filetable                   AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_memory_optimized',             CAST(t.is_memory_optimized            AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('durability',                      CAST(t.durability                     AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('durability_desc',                 CAST(t.durability_desc COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS                AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('temporal_type',                   CAST(t.temporal_type                  AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('temporal_type_desc',              CAST(t.temporal_type_desc COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS             AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('history_table_id',                CAST(t.history_table_id               AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_remote_data_archive_enabled',  CAST(t.is_remote_data_archive_enabled AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   , ('is_external',                      CAST(t.is_external                    AS VARCHAR(255)))
                   ) AS sub(column_name, value)
 WHERE sub.column_name = 'name' AND sub.value = 'my_tbl'
```

PS: instead of CROSS APPLY you could also use UNPIVOT, but it's syntax is more compliciated. In both cases you should need a creator procedure for your function.